# How to create a text widget where people can't enter their own values

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use tkinter to create a text widget that, by pressing buttons on the GUI, numbers will be entered into the text widget, but the person themself can't actually type anything into the widget. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Bind the click event on that button to a function to create said widget.

Answer (score 2):

The tkinter.Text widget has an attribute that allows you to prevent users from editing it's contents: `state`. Example:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.Text(root)
text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH)

text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED) # Or text["state"] = tkinter.DISABLED 

root.mainloop()
```

**Important: you can only insert text into the text widget when it's state is tkinter.NORMAL, and so when you insert text it should look something like:**

```
text.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
text.insert(tkinter.END, "Hello, world!")
text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Accepet answer by clicking check. @user3516628